# Seeking Tips on PAAS Architecture

Tags: java, architecture, web-applications, paas, vaadin

I've developed a java web app using Vaadin, and using Jelastic/MassiveGrid as the PAAS. However, I need advice on proper architecture for my needs.

**Desired Outcome:**

- Users land on my homepage where they can read about the app's features, pricing, view the contact page, etc. If they want to login, they click "Login" in the top-right corner.
- They get re-directed to my app server hosted on my PAAS (Jelastic/MassiveGrid).

**Potential Solution:**

- Purchase a cheap hosting package (such as iPage.com) to host my "landing" page, which will be either simple HTML/CSS/JS or WordPress. It's only goal is inform users and provide contact info, terms of service, etc.
- Keep my PAAS package with MassiveGrid

**Confusion:**

- MassiveGrid offers WordPress so I'm confused whether there's any benefit to using iPage.com as well. I assume it's ideal to separate the logic (app-server) from the administrative details (basic website server).
- If a user registers on my account, their data would be stored in my database on iPage.com. If my app (on PAAS) ever needs to communicate with this database info, it'll need to be across the servers of 2 companies (MassiveGrid and iPage).

**Question:**

- Are 2 separate servers/service providers the best approach here?
- What if I only use MassiveGrid and add another "node" which I then install WordPress on and separate it that way?

Any advice, tips or feedback is welcome. This is my first time hosting a commercial webapp.